# How to get least squares estimates by hand in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, least-squares

I can't figure out how to get the least squares estimates (beta 1 hat and beta not hat) by hand using formulas instead of using functions.

I have tried the formula below, I feel like I need to use a for loop but I just can't figure out how to do it. Once I get beta 1 I should be able to get beta not.

```
x <- toluca$lot 
y <- toluca$work

beta1hat <- (sum(x[i]-mean(x)*sum(y[i] - mean(y))/sum(x[i]-mean(x)^2)
```

It says I is not defined but I don't know what I would define I as because it is a specific value within x.

Comment: R functions like this are vectorised, you don't have to specify the `i` at all. `x <- 1:10` and then take a look at what `x - mean(x)` gives. And `(x - mean(x))^2` etc

Comment: You don't need the `[i]` terms. R handles vectors automagically. Also: be careful with your parentheses and what you're summing.

Comment: You need to also make sure your parentheses make sense. Also ... your formula has too many sums in the numerator.

Comment: ` beta_1_hat <- sum(x-mean(x)*(y-mean(y))/sum(x-mean(x)^2)) `
` beta_0_hat <- mean(y) - beta_1_hat*mean(x)  `  so that would be correct?

Comment: i is not defined because you did not assign any values to it. A generalized form would be solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% (t(x) %*% y)

Answer (score 0):

You can code the matrix form of the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) for the ordinary-least squares estimator in R. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- 1:10
a <- 2
b <- 3

y <- a*x + b + rnorm(10)

xm <- matrix(c(x, rep(1, length(x))), ncol = 2, nrow = 10)
ym <- matrix(y, ncol = 1, nrow = 10)

beta_hat <- MASS::ginv(t(xm) %*% xm) %*% t(xm) %*% ym
```

This gives exactly the same output as `summary(lm(y ~ x))`. Note, however, that the `lm` function is NOT a simple one liner because calculating the inverse of a matrix is a numerically challenging problem, so some precautions must be taken.

Comment: I am wanting to use the formula.

Comment: @StacyWillis then simply use `cov(x,y)/var(x)` to get the slope `a` and estimate `b` once `a` is known (`mean(y - a*x)`).

Comment: why is this giving beta 1 to be infinity? `sum((x-mean(x))*(y-mean(y)))/sum(x-mean(x))^2`

Comment: Your formula is wrong. Use explicit formulas for the variance and covariance.